# How to remove an object from an array, if 2 item properties match from a second array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a `messages[]` array and a `deletedMessages[]` array.
messages:

```
0: {userId: '7d014637', userName: 'me', text: "Let's play cards.", ts: '2022-04-07T22:42:34Z', date: Thu Apr 07 2022 18:42:34 GMT-0400 (GMT-04:00)}
1: {userId: '82f9cae5', userName: 'me', text: 'Lets go to the ball game.', ts: '2022-04-07T21:06:57Z', date: Thu Apr 07 2022 17:06:57 GMT-0400 (GMT-04:00)}
2: {userId: '9e2a4fdb', userName: 'me', text: 'Wreck it ralph', ts: '2022-04-07T22:36:22Z', date: Thu Apr 07 2022 18:36:22 GMT-0400 (GMT-04:00)}
```

deletedMessages:

```
6: {userId: '82f9cae5', userName: 'me', text: 'Lets go to the ball game.', ts: '2022-04-07T21:06:57Z', date: Thu Apr 07 2022 17:06:57 GMT-0400 (GMT-04:00)}
7: {userId: '9e2a4fdb', userName: 'me', text: 'Wreck it ralph', ts: '2022-04-07T22:36:22Z', date: Thu Apr 07 2022 18:36:22 GMT-0400 (GMT-04:00)}
```

object 1 and 2 in `messages` are the exact same as in `deletedMessages` objects 6 and 7.

I'd like to subtract these objects from the `messages` array so that in the end I have only the objects that don't match this criteria. So the end it would just be this.
messages:

```
0: {userId: '7d014637', userName: 'me', text: "Let's play cards.", ts: '2022-04-07T22:42:34Z', date: Thu Apr 07 2022 18:42:34 GMT-0400 (GMT-04:00)}
```

And I would like to do this by finding matching properties. For example the `userId` value and the `ts` value.

I tried using filter like this but it didn't work, I believe because it's not filtering through the deletedMessages array properly.

```
let result = messages.filter(function( obj ) {
    return obj.userId !== deletedMessages.userId && obj.ts !== deletedMessages.ts;
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: `deletedMessages` is an array, you cannot use `deletedMessages.userId` directly. try some array functions like `some`, `every` to match contents of array

Comment: something like `deletedMessages.some(msg => obj.userId === msg.userId)`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use === on an array. Here is one variation.

Using `Array.some`

```js
const arr1 = [{userId: '7d014637', userName: 'me', text: "Let's play cards.", ts: '2022-04-07T22:42:34Z', date: "Thu Apr 07 2022 18:42:34 GMT-0400 (GMT-04:00)"},
{userId: '82f9cae5', userName: 'me', text: 'Lets go to the ball game.', ts: '2022-04-07T21:06:57Z', date:" Thu Apr 07 2022 17:06:57 GMT-0400 (GMT-04:00)"},
 {userId: '9e2a4fdb', userName: 'me', text: 'Wreck it ralph', ts: '2022-04-07T22:36:22Z', date: "Thu Apr 07 2022 18:36:22 GMT-0400 (GMT-04:00)"}]

const deletedMessages = [{userId: '82f9cae5', userName: 'me', text: 'Lets go to the ball game.', ts: '2022-04-07T21:06:57Z', date: "Thu Apr 07 2022 17:06:57 GMT-0400 (GMT-04:00)"},
 {userId: '9e2a4fdb', userName: 'me', text: 'Wreck it ralph', ts: '2022-04-07T22:36:22Z', date: "Thu Apr 07 2022 18:36:22 GMT-0400 (GMT-04:00)"}]

const arr2 = arr1.filter(({ userId, ts }) => !deletedMessages.some(del => userId === del.userId && ts === del.ts))

console.log(arr2)
```

Or create an array of the concatenated values you are looking for.

```js
const arr1 = [{userId: '7d014637', userName: 'me', text: "Let's play cards.", ts: '2022-04-07T22:42:34Z', date: "Thu Apr 07 2022 18:42:34 GMT-0400 (GMT-04:00)"},
{userId: '82f9cae5', userName: 'me', text: 'Lets go to the ball game.', ts: '2022-04-07T21:06:57Z', date:" Thu Apr 07 2022 17:06:57 GMT-0400 (GMT-04:00)"},
 {userId: '9e2a4fdb', userName: 'me', text: 'Wreck it ralph', ts: '2022-04-07T22:36:22Z', date: "Thu Apr 07 2022 18:36:22 GMT-0400 (GMT-04:00)"}]

const deletedMessages = [{userId: '82f9cae5', userName: 'me', text: 'Lets go to the ball game.', ts: '2022-04-07T21:06:57Z', date: "Thu Apr 07 2022 17:06:57 GMT-0400 (GMT-04:00)"},
 {userId: '9e2a4fdb', userName: 'me', text: 'Wreck it ralph', ts: '2022-04-07T22:36:22Z', date: "Thu Apr 07 2022 18:36:22 GMT-0400 (GMT-04:00)"}]
 
 const delArr = deletedMessages.map(({userId,ts}) => `${userId}${ts}`)
 console.log(delArr)
 const arr2 = arr1.filter(({userId,ts}) => !delArr.includes(`${userId}${ts}`))
 console.log(arr2)
```

Comment: what is the advantage of creating a new array with strings and then matching? why not directly use array methods?

Comment: Because you would have to use find on the del array for each element - I would think my version would be faster

Comment: you don't have to use `find`. there are other methods like `some` which return early. so best case would be O(1), worst would be O(N).  i would really like to see some benchmarks :D

Comment: [Libik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71796720/295783) suggested `O(n^2)` but I have not run a performance. `includes` also returns when found

Comment: O(N^2) will for the whole filter loop, i'm just talking about the filter callback. `includes` doesn't allow passing a callback

Comment: @boxdox see update

Comment: i didn't mean to question you, i was just trying to know why one method was better than the other. anyways, both results look identical, so it's okay only for small data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the body of your filter function

```
let result = messages.filter(function( obj ) {
    // here
});
```

With method like this, you would need to go through every deletedMessage and if you find the same message there, you filter it (by returning false).

If you are interested about performance, this alghoritm is `O(n^2)`, therefore if you got i.e. thousands of messages and deletedMessages it can become very CPU intensive.

If you want better performace, you would need to create i.e. Map first, put there all deletedMessages and then select from Map inside the function (instead of going through every deteledMessage)